Finding a word for a thermodynamic process
"A ___ is a physical object with mass and volume that performs work (distinct from its thermal energy) by manipulating energy in one or more forms through internal processes, generating heat from inefficiencies, and having a finite lifespan under standard conditions."
Can someone help me find the word that fits this definition?
I though about 'engine', 'machine' and 'device' but they are not broad enough. And 'system' is too broad.
Please note that 'work' is in a more general sense, not just simple mechanical work, for example electric field work.

"Combustion engine" fits the definition, but the word is not a synonym.

This describes any composite physical object. They all have mass and volume, perform work, release heat and eventually disintegrate. 'Engine', 'machine' and 'device' suggest human artifacts used for some purpose, but it is not clear from the description that is even intended. Do stars or viruses qualify?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Conifold not totally. I think it doesnt work for all composite physical objects because the work performed by it has to be different from the regular thermal energy of the system or the random motion of particles within the system. In that sense a rock wouldn't fit the definition for example. Its not performing any work besides at the atomic level with its thermal energy. I think stars qualify, im not sure about viruses.

"Has to be different from the regular thermal energy of the system or the random motion of particles" is not a workable distinction. What counts as "regular" and "random" is vague and purpose dependent. Even rocks can implement finite state automata, for example.

I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited for Physics or English StackExchange.

An engine generates work from energy, a machine changes force, and a device suggests an artifact. It sounds like you are looking for something like "electromechanical machine" to me.

Sounds like a heat engine.

likely you want heat engine, but 'physical object' there might be an issue, since 'heat engine' is exceptionally broad and can refer to just the process

@Kaia No, it's not a heat engine. A heat engine needs a heat source and usually performs mechanical work. A counterexample would be a computer. A computer is not a heat engine, as far as I'm aware, but it fits the definition outlined, given that the work is performed by the electrical fields pulling the electrons into the transistors' channels. See Electric field work.

You're looking for a dissipative system, you're just missing some background knowledge needed to frame it so that you can define it from scratch.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_system
